# Trying to convert lines to points

Tags: qgis, python, mmqgis, lines-to-points

I'm using QGIS and MMQGIS and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Ana Eljall/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 956, in run
                message = mmqgis_geometry_convert(self.iface, layername, newtype, splitnodes, savename, 1)
              File "C:/Users/Ana Eljall/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py", line 2398, in mmqgis_geometry_convert
                if (feature.geometry().wkbType() == QGis.WKBPoint) or \
            AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wkbType'
```

Comment: Can you describe what kind of data is in your layer, and what MMQGIS function you started?

Comment: My guess: you have line without any geometry.  Add something like 'if feature.geometry() is not None:' before asking anything about the geometry.

Comment: Can you upload your shapefile to a public server so that others could test it? Also, have you considered using other line-to-point conversion tools from the **Processing Toolbox**?